# Boost::list_of not able to do template deduction for slightly complicated data structure

Tags: c++, boost

I have to use cross platform code. And right now , I am stuck using `VS2012` , which does not support `C++11` , uniform initialization. So , I am using `boost::list_of`.

For simple cases, this works. However, for a slightly complicated data structure , this does not seem to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::assign;

int main() {

class NodeInfo
{
    public:
        NodeInfo (int Parent, int childLeft, int childRight) :
            m_parent (Parent), m_childLeft(childLeft), m_childRight(childRight)
            {   

            }
        private:
            int m_parent;
            int m_childLeft;
            int m_childRight;
};
typedef std::vector<NodeInfo> MyData1;
MyData1 expData =  list_of(NodeInfo(1,2,3)) (NodeInfo(3,4,5));

typedef std::tuple<int , std::vector<NodeInfo>> MyData2;
MyData2 expData21 =  std::make_tuple(10 , expData);

 // I would have really liked the following:
 // error:
 MyData2 expData22 =  std::make_tuple(10 , list_of(NodeInfo(1,2,3) (NodeInfo(3,4,5) )));

//error:From the example in boost doc, this should work. 
MyData2 expData3 =  list_of<MyData2> (std::make_tuple(10 , expData));

MyData2 expData4;
// error: Most probably need to write my own list_inserter for MyTest,
// after turning MyTest into a class. 
// I really don't want to go this route, if the other options are at all 
// possible. Why extend the boost library, if it's at all possible ? 
insert( expData4 )
    ( std::make_tuple(10 , expData) )( std::make_tuple(20 , expData) ); 

return 0;
}
```

I have added a partial code here. 
https://ideone.com/kIYDu0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the best way to make this work smoothlessly is to extend the library (or just write your own helper functions).

However, the things you try were never features. The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#list_of) shows how to assign from `list_of` to a vector:

```
Tuple mytuple2 = std::make_tuple(10, 
        list_of(NodeInfo(1, 2, 3))(NodeInfo(3, 4, 5)).to_container(std::get<1>(mytuple2))
    );
```

More notes:

- Looks to me you forgot to make `expData3` and `expData4` a container.
- at some point you use `std::make_tuple(1,2,3)` as a `NodeInfo`. I don't see how that should work

Here's the full lists with fixes/workarounds:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ade7b7a1ee7ac5d)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::assign;

int main() {

    class NodeInfo {
      public:
        NodeInfo(int Parent, int childLeft, int childRight)
                : m_parent(Parent), m_childLeft(childLeft), m_childRight(childRight) {}

      private:
        int m_parent;
        int m_childLeft;
        int m_childRight;
    };

    typedef std::vector<NodeInfo> NodeInfos;
    NodeInfo node1(1,2,3), node2(3,4,5);
    NodeInfos infos = list_of(node1)(node2);

    typedef std::tuple<int, std::vector<NodeInfo> > Tuple;
    Tuple mytuple = std::make_tuple(10, infos);

    // I would have really liked the following:
    Tuple mytuple2 = std::make_tuple(10, 
            list_of(NodeInfo(1, 2, 3))(NodeInfo(3, 4, 5)).to_container(std::get<1>(mytuple2))
        );

    std::vector<Tuple> 
        mytuples = list_of<Tuple>(std::make_tuple(10, infos)),
        mytuples2;

    //// still figuring this out:
    // insert(mytuples2)(Tuple(10, infos))(Tuple(20, infos));
}
```

Comment: yap, I was missing  the to_container; from the doc, it wasn't clear to me, what sort of type dedication can be supported by list_of. Thanks for clearing that out for me. For now , I will run with that. I will probably write my own list_inserter as you pointed out

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  // I would have really liked the following:
>  // error:
>  MyData2 expData22 =  std::make_tuple(10 , list_of(NodeInfo(1,2,3) (NodeInfo(3,4,5) )));
> ```

You just got the parentheses wrong. The following should work:

```
MyData2 expData22 =  std::make_tuple(10 , list_of(NodeInfo(1,2,3))(NodeInfo(3,4,5)));
```

Comment: It would have been pretty simple to test it, of course

Comment: I did the parentheses wrong, I was trying out a few things. But that is not the problem. As @sehe rightly pointed out, the issue lies somewhere else